# How to use match() in if else condition correctly. (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, dynamic, match

I have dynamic response data that either has a completely random string, or a string like `Johnny likes to eat {food} for breakfast` data as I'm trying to match.

```
var data = response.body
if (data.match(/Johnny likes to eat(.*)for breakfast/)[0]) {
  console.log("Johnny in fact likes to eat" + data.match(/Johnny likes to eat(.*)for breakfast/)[1])
} else {
  console.log("Johnny eats nothing") //this doesnt get executed, just logs null
}
```

If the statement is false, it would just log `null` and not to the `else`. How can I make it that it would?

Comment: Is "Johnny likes to eat {food} for breakfast" always the structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const data = "Johnny likes to eat apples for breakfast"

const string = data.split(" ")[4] // Gets the fifth string 
if (string != "for")
  console.log("Johnny in fact likes to eat " + string)
else
  console.log("Johnny eats nothing")
```